# Multiple Linux distros break BIOS fan control?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, bios, asus, fan

I have a strange (and annoying) problem with my ASUS [UX32LA](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/UX32LA/0409_E8880_A.pdf?_ga=2.247853956.2076706328.1555531077-1959752819.1554754024) notebook: I suspect that multiple Linux distros (Ubuntu 16.04 and newer major versions using the [4.18.0-17-generic kernel](https://linuxsecurity.com/advisories/ubuntu/ubuntu-3930-2-linux-kernel-hwe-vulnerabilities?rss), plus Fedora 28 LiveUSB), somehow breaks BIOS control over fans.

I also tried upgrading Ubuntu to 5.x kernel line. Every attempt was followed by a BIOS re-flash. No attempt brought success.

Why?

- One day (don't remember when, not using this notebook very often) fans started to work at full speed when using Linux (it was 4.x line kernel).
- First I though of trying reboot to Windows to see if problem persists. It turned out that indeed fans were still at full speed on Windows.
- Then I though that it may be a hardware issue. I gave computer to the repair and I was amused when they told me that re-flashing BIOS made fans work properly on Windows (they refused to check on Linux...). No hardware issue.
- Having computer back I operated Windows for some time (week or so) to see if the issue is gone. It was.
- After booting into Linux the issue was back as soon as CPU temperature rose enough for the fan to turn on. It turned on to full speed and remained so. After that it's not important if it's Linux or Windows. Fans at full speed.
- Re-flashing BIOS solves the issue as long as Linux is not booted. On Windows fans work normally.

I don't expect easy answer here, but maybe someone could give me a hint where to start debugging? I found some posts that it may be related to the [Differentiated System Description Table](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DSDT)...

Comment: Unfortunately, no additional information on the back of the computer. Output of `dmidecode`: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC., product Name: UX32LA, version: 1.0, SKU Number: ASUS-Ultrabook, Family: UX

Comment: Steps to debug: 1) Go through `dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog` / `journalctl` after boot to see if you have any linux kernel modules that detect fans and/or temperature sensors, and or any packages like `fancontrol` that want to control the fans directly. While you are at that, edit question to indicate *what* fans and termperature sensors you have, and how they are wired up. 2) If your SM (system management) BIOS is capable of controlling the fans (better check this, unless you want to deal with overheated components), you can disable the Linux fan control (details depend on the package used).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the BIOS setting before installing Linux. The common BIOS optiona for Linux installation is to *enable* **CSM support** and *select* **UEFI and legacy support** option in the boot device control. Then, in the *secure boot* option, set the os type to ***other os***.

Comment: Enabling CSM solved the issue. I did a stress test (`stresss --cpu 4` for 15 minutes), temerature rised, fan RPM as well, but both were in expected range. Thanks a lot!